# Null Values In Sql Server Complex Joins

Tags: sql-server

I have Five tables and I put left joins among them. I want that null values are replaced by today's date. How can I do that? My query is as follows. All tables have only two columns of `ordernumber` and `orderdate`.

```
select * from table1 left join table2 left join table3 left join table4 left join table5
```

Comment: isnull(colname,getdate())

Comment: KumarHarsh how can i used it in query mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `ISNULL` (or `COALESCE`), with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to default to today, and a `CONVERT` (or `CAST`) to get just the date portion. I've assumed 2008 or later.

```
select 
   CONVERT(DATE, ISNULL(table1.orderdate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) as t1OrderDate,
   CONVERT(DATE, ISNULL(table2.orderdate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) as t2OrderDate,
   -- etc
from table1 
  left join table2 
    on table1.ordernumber = table2.ordernumber 
       -- Same for the joins to table3, table4 and table5
```